# Как передать переменную в обработчик события?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Код:

```
var slider = startSlider('.slider');

$('ul.tabs__controls').on('click', 'li:not(.is-active)', function() {
    $(this).addClass('is-active').siblings().removeClass('is-active')
.parents('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__box').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(150).siblings('div.tabs__box').hide();
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать переменную ***slider*** внутрь обработчика?

Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Её не нужно передавать, она и так там доступна, сделайте: `console.log(slider);` и посмотрите консоль.

А так-же у вас излишние цепочки селекторов которые "не оптимально" используют ресурсы клиента, задайте объектам управляющие классы что-то типа `.js-tab-head, .js-tab-body. js-btn-order` и используйте их!